# Is there an empty/clean version of Android for tablets?

Tags: kiosk-mode

All I want is a tablet that only runs one application (developed by me) on startup.
Is there a "clean" version of Android that I can use for this? By clean or empty I mean an OS without all the unwanted features.

Basically, my app needs to connect to the Internet, access the camera within my app, and send and receive data from sensors and other external devices.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the [tag:kiosk-mode] tag to your question. It sounds like the kind of thing you're looking for. You might like to take a look at some of the existing questions, but it's likely you'll have to make your own custom ROM to achieve this.

Comment: I thought hard about leaving a comment on this for fear of it being "advertising." FWIW, you might want to consider an off-the-shelf solution. Android doesn't necessarily need to be "cleaned" of the other stuff, as long as it is locked down. [KioWare Kiosk Software for Android](http://www.kioware.com) and Site Kiosk offer products that do this; the goal of nearly all of these products is going to be to lock down the system so that users are unable to run or view anything other than the explicitly allowed URLs or apps. In the interest of full disclosure, I work for KioWare.

Comment: See also: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241375/single-purpose-android-tablet-for-handicapped-person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Cyanogenmod or any number of custom roms, but it sounds like you'll need to develop a specific rom for your situation.

If you only want the user to run a single app, I would imagine you'd have to develop an app that declares itself as a Home Screen/Launcher, and have your ROM only include that app as the main Launcher.

This is basically how Barnes & Noble made the Nook Simple Touch. Their own Launcher is very limited and doesn't let you install apps or see anything that looks like Android. As soon as you get root via an exploit, you can easily install your own launcher that gives you access to the standard android interface and turns the Nook Simple Touch into a fully fledged (if limited) tablet.

A specific implementation is outside the focus of this stackexchange site, but you can get programming advice at stackoverflow.com