# Permanently disabling Galaxy S3's calling and SMS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, kiosk-mode

I've procured myself a Galaxy S3 and I intend to mess with it.

I'd like to have a phone that runs one app and one app only (mine).

I want to disable calling, texting, app installs. Come to think of it, I still want to be able to receive texts, but not send them.

Removing the base apps isn't necessary as long as they're made non-functional in some other way like crashing on startup or something. Outgoing calls or picking up incoming calls is a no-no.

What's the best way to go about disabling these features?

Here's an "artist's" rendition of what I want to see ideally:

[image]

Comment: What you're asking for is called [kiosk-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiosk-mode) – and your question is almost identical to this one you might wish to check: [Is there an empty/clean version of Android for tablets?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/57441/16575) Quoting: *All I want is a tablet that only runs one application (developed by me)* Sounds familiar? ;)

Comment: Yessir, that answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update! So we will mark this one a duplicate to it, making it a "reference" to find the other one.