# Single-purpose Android Tablet for handicapped person

Tags: accessibility, kiosk-mode

My brother is profoundly disabled.  He enjoys working word search problems.  I live 1400 miles away from him, and I only get to visit him once per year. During that time I install  different word search apps on his Fire tablet.  But within a few days, something happens and the Fire sits unused until my next visit.

What I would like to do is create a tablet that only runs the word search puzzle, and nothing else.  I would like it to boot in this mode, and run only this app.  Ever. Until the tablet dies for good

He has an effective IQ below 60, and he cannot understand ads, other apps, complicated boot up sequences.

I have heard about the kiosk mode, maybe that would work, but I have not been able to understand how to implement.

Ideally, I would buy an inexpensive tablet, configure it to run one word-search app, and send it to him in the mail.  And for the most part, never need to worry about it.  It would be a "tablet as an appliance".

Could I please get advice on how to do this?  I lament my inability to make a tablet work in a way that would let my brother tap into the larger potential of Android, but just having a single app would be a game changer.

Comment: Hopefully someone will be able to help you and your brother here.  I know there are very simple launchers, but I'm not sure if they can disable the hardware buttons that are used for other functions.  BTW, I suspect your brother's intelligence is well above what is reflected by an IQ test.  Although I don't doubt he has a unique brain, engaging in word search puzzles requires performing multiple concurrent complex cognitiive tasks.  Finding enjoyment out of them also provides a clue of a higher level of functioning than a simple IQ test reveals.

Comment: For cross-reference purposes, I found the following related QA.  It's quite old and not exactly what you are asking, but may be helpful: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57441/is-there-an-empty-clean-version-of-android-for-tablets

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at screen pinning. It is available in all Android devices and allow a specific app to be locked on UI.

https://support.google.com/android/answer/9455138?hl=en

Alternatively,there are multiple third party apps available on Play store which will allow you to set kiosk mode on any device with apps of your choice.